# Ajax in loop for html output - Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, callback, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to retrieve multiple json files and place each file's data into Bootstrap 3 Tabs. I realize that the getJSON call is not done before the data is appended at the end of the function, but I don't understand callbacks that well. How can I set up a callback when I am adding html to a variable like in the example below?

```
function loadTabs(p){
    var htmlTabs = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
    var htmlContent = '<div class="tab-content">';

    for (var i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        if (i == 0){
            htmlTabs += '<li class="active"><a href="'+i+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+i+'</a></li>';
            htmlContent += '<div class="tab-pane active" id="'+i+'">';
        }
        else {
            htmlTabs += '<li><a href="#'+i+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+i+'</a></li>';
            htmlContent += '<div class="tab-pane" id="'+i+'">';
        }
        (function(i) {
            $.getJSON('sampleFile_0' + i + '.json', function(data) {})
            .done(function(data){
                htmlContentnt += '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">'
                    for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                        if (ttid == data[j].tid){
                            htmlContent += '<tr><td>' + data[j].cl + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                        else if (otid == data[j].tid){
                            htmlContent += '<tr><td>' + data[j].cl + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                    }
                htmlContent += '</table>';
            })
        })(i);
        htmlContent += '</div>';
    };

    htmlTabs += '</ul>';
    htmlContent += '</div>';

    $('#block').append(htmlTabs + htmlContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using promises, so the trick here is that you need to capture all of those promises and outside of your loop use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to only occur AFTER all of the promises have completed. This should get you started:

```
 var promises = [];

 for (var i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
    if (i == 0){
        htmlTabs += '<li class="active"><a href="'+i+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+i+'</a></li>';
        htmlContent += '<div class="tab-pane active" id="'+i+'">';
    }
    else {
        htmlTabs += '<li><a href="#'+i+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+i+'</a></li>';
        htmlContent += '<div class="tab-pane" id="'+i+'">';
    }
    (function(i) {
        promises.push($.getJSON('sampleFile_0' + i + '.json')
        .done(function(data){
            htmlContentnt += '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">'
                for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if (ttid == data[j].tid){
                        htmlContent += '<tr><td>' + data[j].cl + '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    else if (otid == data[j].tid){
                        htmlContent += '<tr><td>' + data[j].cl + '</td></tr>';
                    }
                }
            htmlContent += '</table>';
        }));
    })(i);
    htmlContent += '</div>';
};

...
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){
   $('#block').append(htmlTabs + htmlContent);
});
```